# cascade={"remove"} VS orphanRemoval=true VS ondelete="CASCADE

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity, cascade

I tried to gather some information about the following way to delete automatically child entity when a parent entity is deleted. Seems that the most common way is to use one those three annotation: `cascade={"remove"}` OR `orphanRemoval=true` OR `ondelete="CASCADE"`.

I am a bit confused about the third one: `ondelete="CASCADE"`, as the explanation in doctrine official documentation about this one are very scarce) and I would love if someone could **confirm me the following information** I gathered and understand from my research on the net and experience...

What does it do?

`cascade={"remove"}`
==> the entity on the inverse side is deleted when the owning side entity is. Even if you are in a `ManyToMany` with other owning side entity.

- should be used on collection (so in `OneToMany` or `ManyToMany` relationship)
- implementation in the ORM

`orphanRemoval=true`
==> the entity on the inverse side is deleted when the owning side entity is AND it is not connected to any other owning side entity anymore. (ref.  [doctrine official_doc](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/xml-mapping.html?highlight=orphanremoval#defining-many-to-one-associations)

- implementation in the ORM
- can be used with `OneToOne`, `OneToMany` or `ManyToMany`

`onDelete="CASCADE"`
==> this will add On Delete Cascade to the foreign key column in the database

- This strategy is a bit tricky to get right but can be very powerful and fast. (ref.  [doctrine official_doc](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html?highlight=tricky#removing-entities) ... but haven't read more explanations)
- ORM has to do less work (compared to the two previous ways of doing it) and therefore should have better performance.

**other information**

- all those 3 ways of doing are implemented on bidirectional relationship entities (***right???***)
- using `cascade={"remove"}` completely by-passes any foreign key onDelete=CASCADE. (ref. [doctrine_official_doc](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html?highlight=tricky#removing-entities))

### EXAMPLE ON HOW TO USE IT IN CODE

- `orphanRemoval` and `cascade={"remove"}` are defined in the inversed entity class.
- `ondelete="CASCADE"` is defined in the owner entity
- you can also just write `@ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")` and let doctrine handle the column names

**cascade={"remove"}**

```
/**
* @OneToMany(targetEntity="Phonenumber", mappedBy="contact", cascade={"remove"})
*/
protected $Phonenumbers
```

**orphanRemoval=true**

```
/**
* @OneToMany(targetEntity="Phonenumber", mappedBy="contact", orphanRemoval=true)
*/
protected $Phonenumbers
```

**onDelete="CASCADE"**

```
/** 
* @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Contact", inversedBy="phonenumbers")
* @JoinColumn(name="contact_id", referencedColumnName="contact_id", onDelete="CASCADE")
*/ 
protected $contact;
```

Comment: it has a good explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25515007/doctrine-cascade-remove-vs-orphanremoval-true/25519856#25519856

Answer (score 76):

`onDelete="CASCADE"` is managed by the database itself. `cascade={"remove"}` is managed by doctrine.

`onDelete="CASCADE"` is faster because the operations are performed on database level instead by doctrine. The removing is performed by the database server and not Doctrine. With `cascade={"remove"}` doctrine has to manage the entity itself and will perform extra checks to see if it doesn't have any other owning entities. When no other exists it will delete the entity. But this creates overhead.

---

**cascade={"remove"}**

- the entity on the inverse side is deleted when the owning side entity is. Even if you are in a manytomany with other owning side entity. ***No, if the entity is owned by something else. It won't be deleted.***
- should be used on collection (so in OneToMany or ManyToMany relationship)
- implementation in the ORM

**orphanRemoval="true"**

- the entity on the inverse side is deleted when the owning side entity is AND it is not connected to any other owning side entity anymore. ***Not exactly, this makes doctrine behave like it is not owned by an other entity, and thus remove it.***
- implementation in the ORM
- can be used with OneToOne, OnetoMany or ManyToMany

**onDelete="CASCADE"**

- this will add On Delete Cascade to the foreign key column IN THE DATABASE
- This strategy is a bit tricky to get right but can be very powerful and fast. (this is a quote from doctrine official tutorial... but haven't seen much more explaination)
- ORM has to do less work (compared to the two previous way of doing) and therefore should have better performance.

Comment: @ waaghals. About your comments on the cascade={"remove"} ==> I have a ManyToMany relationship between entity Article and Category. When I remove an Article ($em->remove($article);) it does remove all categories linked to this article EVEN if those categories are also linked to other articles. so I would say that it does not behave as you write.

Comment: @ waaghals. About your comments on the orphanRemoval="true" The sentence I wrote "the entity on the inverse side is deleted when the owning side entity is, and it is not own by any other entities" is quoted from doctrine official pages. [doctrine=orphanremoval](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/xml-mapping.html?highlight=orphanremoval).

Comment: @Alexis_D, fully agreed with your comments
The answer is incorrect and can be really confusing for newbies

Comment: One of the clearer examples I've read: https://gist.github.com/pylebecq/f844d1f6860241d8b025

Comment: @VictorS' link is very clear. I'm no longer working with Doctrine so feel I cannot update my answer without knowing first hand how it works.

If someone could update my answer that would be great.

Comment: **What can be done to improve the answer?** I am working with Doctrine since 2 weeks and got in touch with these topics lately. I can help with some of my experience, but i rather support offical expert-level information.