# what does "the entities are privately owned" means (as seen in Doctrine official documentation)?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity

I have read the following in doctrine documentation that does not mean much to me:

> When using the `orphanRemoval=true` option Doctrine makes the
> assumption that the entities are privately owned and will NOT be
> reused by other entities.

here the link where you can find the sentence in its context. [doctrine official documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#orphan-removal)

Can someone could give me an example of privately own entities in a `ManyToMany` relationship between entities?

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you're storing some user settings in a `Settings` entity which is attached to a `User` entity via a One-To-Many or One-To-One relation, the `Settings` entity won't be shared amongst several users, nor will it be reused if it's referenced user gets removed, you could say that `Settings` is privately owned by `User` and would become an orphan if `User` gets deleted, `orphanRemoval=true` prevents that from happening by deleting `Settings` when its "mother" `User` entity gets removed.

Some other questions on SO that you might find interesting :

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/27473401/4114297
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/25519856/4114297

Concerning Many-To-Many relations, you can use `orphanRemoval` on such relations and Doctrine will simply remove attached entities, even if they are still attached to other entities.
Note that even though this option will work on Many-To-Many relations, it is not officially documented for such relations :

- OneToOne : http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-onetoone
- OneToMany : http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-onetomany
- ManyToMany : http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-manytomany

I don't think there's any example of a privately owned entity on a Many-To-Many relation, or it wouldn't be Many-To-Many, but Doctrine just makes the **assumption** it is, and will proceed to remove attached entities anyway.

Comment: ok thanks. I make my question more focused on ManyToMany relationship because orphanRemoval can be applied to such Entity relationship. Do you have an exemple for that?

Comment: Oh okay, I'll edit my answer, by the way, the example I gave looks more like One-To-One relation than One-To-Many

Comment: which of the following do you mean by "attached to other entities": (1) other records of a same entity **OR** (2) other records of a différent class. (in my experience I think it is 2)

Comment: Well I guess that would apply to both cases