# Symfony Integrity constraint violation

Tags: database, symfony, doctrine

I tried cascade remove on the 'file' entity that keeps my 'expanse' entity from removing. But this doesn't work.

The error:

Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`zioo`.`files`, CONSTRAINT `FK_6354059F395DB7B` FOREIGN KEY (`expense_id`) REFERENCES `expenses` (`id`))

The file entity code:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Expense", inversedBy="files", cascade={"remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="expense_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $expense;
```

The expanse entity code:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="File", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="file_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $file = null;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="File", mappedBy="expense", cascade={"remove"})
 */
protected $files;
```

If a expanse gets deleted the file associated with it should be deleted too.

Comment: One solution is to delete the 'file' entity in the 'expense' controller like this:

        $expense_files = $em->getRepository('ZPAdminBundle:File')-
        >findBy(['expense' => $expense]);
        foreach($expense_files as $e) {
            $em->remove($e);
        }
        $em->flush();

But I guess this is bad practice because it should be possible to delete the file entity by using doctrine..

Answer (score 2):

Using **cascade={"remove"}** the entity won't be deleted if it is owned by something else. The issue seems to be caused by doctrine, as the expanse entity has 2 relations to file entity and this causes doctrine to "think" that your file entity is owned by something else and not send a delete to database for it, before trying to delete the expanse.

As a result when it tries to delete the expanse this error is thrown.

To test it, remove `private $file = null;`relation and will see that it will work.

To overcome this, I suggest to use `onDelete="CASCADE"` on the owning side:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Expense", inversedBy="files", cascade={"remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="expense_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
private $expense;
```

In this case, you no longer need `cascade={"remove"}`:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="File", mappedBy="expense")
 */
protected $files;
```

[Doctrine delete relation options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27472538/cascade-remove-vs-orphanremoval-true-vs-ondelete-cascade)