# Delete ManyToMany Doctrine2 relationship

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, many-to-many

In a Doctrine entity I've got this configuration:

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="PriceRate", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="product_rates",
 *   joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id",referencedColumnName="id")},
 *   inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="rate_id",referencedColumnName="id")})
 */
protected $rates;
```

When I delete the entity it tries to delete the `price_rate` table first, instead of the joined table so I get the following error:

> Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent
>   row: a foreign key constraint fails (`uniski`.`product_rates`,
>   CONSTRAINT `FK_15A90A8FBC999F9F` FOREIGN KEY (`rate_id`) REFERENCES
>   `price_rate` (`id`))

Why is it not trying to delete the joined table rows first? I've tried to add `onDelete` statements on the join table columns but it didn't work.

This is a unidirectional relationship because **PriceRate** is used by other entities, therefore i'm using a ManyToMany relationship.

The only way it works is before removing the entity is to clear the ArrayCollection of the child entities like so:

```
$product->removeAllRate(); //it does this: $this->rates->clear();

$em->remove($product);
$em->flush();
```

Thanks!

Comment: this post helped to me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257004/doctrine2-symfony2-cascading-remove-integrity-constraint-violation-1451. Regards

Answer (score 0):

In the entity, you have to specify ManyToMany relation as well. This is the reason. Example:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="rates")
 */
private $products;
```

Comment: May be this is why there is no shorter way to do it,  I have to remove first all children entities. I can't add the other side relationship because the rates is shared among other types of entities. If  rates are only used by products I could use your solution. A part from the archeticture issue, if I don't change it, removing the child entities first is the olny way, which is not so bad at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, with this specific:

> This is a unidirectional relationship because PriceRate is used by other entities, therefore i'm using a ManyToMany relationship.

I could make it works with adding `onDelete="cascade"` on both joinColumns
So mine looks like that:

```
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="PriceRate", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="product_rates",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="cascade")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="rate_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true, onDelete="cascade")}
 * )
```

Note that I have a few differences: my `cascade=` is more restrictive here, I have a `unique=true` on the `inverseJoinColumns`, and I didn't need the `orphanRemoval`