# Symfony Doctrine Cascade deleted

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have table Users and CodeProjectNotificationLater and use

```
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt")
```

and relation One user To Many CodeProjectNotificationLater, when I deleted Users(set deletedAt) my CodeProjectNotificationLater not set deletedAt, but must be. because I use cascade persist and **remove**. But in user I have one more field developer, but another relation - Many users for one developer and when I deleted Users(set deletedAt) my developer deleted(set deletedAt) too. How to cascade deleted CodeProjectNotificationLater ?

Users entity

```
    /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CodeProjectNotificationLater", mappedBy="users", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
public $notification_later;

    /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Developer", inversedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="developer_id", nullable = true, referencedColumnName="id")
 * @Expose()
 * @Groups({"get_team_developer", "get_developer_by_id"})
 */
protected $developer;
```

and CodeProjectNotificationLater entity

```
    /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Users", inversedBy="notification_later", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable = true, referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $users;
```

Developer entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Users", mappedBy="developer",  cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @Expose()
 * @Groups({"for_project", "for_all_projects", "for_project_bit"})
 */
protected $user;
```

**UPDATE**

I try add orphanRemoval=true but still deletedAt empty in table CodeProjectNotificationLater

```
    /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CodeProjectNotificationLater", mappedBy="users", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 */
public $notification_later;
```

Comment: add onDelete="CASCADE" to your JoinTable annotation seems to be the trick

Comment: in Users I have not JoinTable, only @ORM\OneToMany for CodeProjectNotificationLater and cascade={"persist", "remove"}

Comment: My bad ! so add "orphanRemoval=true" to your OneToMany annotation same as : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12895724/doctrine-2-cascade-remove-doesnt-seem-to-be-working

Comment: I try, update  question, still not deltedAt, some magic

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

```
    /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CodeProjectNotificationLater", mappedBy="users", orphanRemoval=true)
 */
public $notification_later;
```

deleted clear in DB

if in  CodeProjectNotificationLater use

```
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt")
```

in DB have data in deletedAT